# Different type of depths for an ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let R be a commutative ring and if necessary we may assume that R is sufficiently nice, meaning it is Noetherian, a local ring, ... (the ring I have in mind is that of formal power series in n variables)

Let M be an R-module, possibly finitely generated, and I an ideal in R. Then the depth of I on M
is the supremum of all M-regular sequences of I in M, where a sequence $(r_1,\dots, r_k)$ in R is M-regular if $r_i$ is a non-zero-divisor in $M/(r_1,\dots, r_{i-1})M$.

My Question: is there also a definition for a number j such that all corresponding j-tuples are regular sequences, would such a definition even make sense and if so is it used somewhere?

I am thinking about something like: Let I be an finitely generated ideal with generators $r_1, \dots , r_k$. Define the $\widetilde{depth}$ of I on M to be the maximum $2\le j\in \mathbb{N}$ due to:
\begin{equation*}
\forall i_1 \in \{1,\dots, k\}: \ r_{i_1} \text{ is a non-zero-divisor in M}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\forall 2\le l\le j \forall i_l\in \{1,\dots, k\}\setminus \{ i_1, \dots, i_{l-1}\}: \ r_{i_l} \text{ is a non-zero-divisor in }M/(r_{i_1},\dots ,r_{i_{l-1}})M
\end{equation*}
We set $j=1$ if only the first condition holds and if that is not the case we define $\widetilde{depth}=0$.

Comment: A note: this depends on the choice of the generating set for $I$. For example, Let $R=k[\![x,y]\!]$, $M=R/(xy)$, and $I=(x,y)$.  Of course neither $x$ nor $y$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$, however $x+y,x$ is also a minimal generating set for $I$, and $x+y$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$.

Comment: You are right. It should probably be seen as a suggestion rather than a definition.. Would it help to assume that the original module M is free?

Comment: No taking $M$ free doesn't resolve this matter. Indeed, we could tweak the example to have $R=k[\![x,y,z]\!]$, $M=R$, and $I=(xy,yz,xz)$. Taking $(xy,yz,yz+xz)$ as another minimal generating set of $I$ exhibits similar behavior. Another note: if your aim is merely to find minimal generators of the ideal $I$ which are part of a regular sequence on $M$ this can always be achieved up to the depth of $I$ on $M$: use prime avoidance to find an element of $I$ which lies outside $\mathfrak{m}I$ and each associated prime of $M$, go modulo this element and proceed inductively.